# Ripple effect for lollipop views

Tags: android, material-design

I have been developing an app for Lollipop (API 21).

When I change the `Button` color to something, the ripple effect doesn't works.

I found some third party libraries for the ripple effect, but I want to do this with standard API.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607339/lollipop-rippledrawable-vs-selector-for-pre-lollipop) didn't help either.

XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
   />
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to set your button's background to a RippleDrawable which you can define in XML. (I'll name it `holo_blue_ripple.xml`)

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/white"> <!-- ripple color -->

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/> <!-- normal color -->

</ripple>
```

Then reference it with `android:background="@drawable/holo_blue_ripple"`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I was wondering how I can apply corner radius with this technique?
I have added following lines in the `holo_blue_ripple.xml` but it isn't working:
  
`<item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="15dip"/>
        </shape>
</item>`

Comment: I figured the solution. Here is that:
`<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"> <!-- ripple color -->


    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
           
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/> <!-- normal color -->

</ripple>

`

Comment: What to do for Pre-Lollipop versions?

Comment: Where to put this xml ? Bcz ripple will not work bellow 21.

Comment: @Prince you can put it in the `drawable-v21` folder.

Comment: how can I programmatically alter the "normal color" in the XML above ?

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    ...
 />
```

Based on [this tutorial](http://code.hootsuite.com/tips-and-tricks-for-android-material-support-library-2-electric-boogaloo/) and [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Touch)

Comment: Unless you want to customize your ripple effect, that's the simplest solution in my opinion.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/ Effect is- color change when clicked.
My android version is 5.0 only. Could you help?

Answer (score 7):

Also `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` canbe used for circular ripple effect.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/ Effect is- color change when clicked.
My android version is 5.0 only. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this attribute

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

This is the simplest way to show ripple effect in your view/layout.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/ Effect is- color change when clicked.
My android version is 5.0 only. Could you help?
adding this to a button