# RecyclerView item touch to highlight

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I am using a `RecyclerView` and I am not able to see any feedback when I touch on the item of the `RecyclerView`. How do I achieve it?

I am trying to show a feedback to the user when they are touching the row of `RecyclerView`. Something like a ripple effect.

I want to know how to achieve it in a specific row of the `RecyclerView`.

This is the recycler view's custom row layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_row"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#F1F1F1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the layout of the `Activity` having the `RecyclerView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer_header">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle_imageview"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_pic"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="John Doe"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/circle_imageview"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/circle_imageview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/circle_imageview"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Transaction Technologies"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I just need to highlight/give feedback of the row which is being touched by the user. How do I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi: not even close

Comment: remove this android:background="@color/windowBackground"

Comment: that background is the FragmentDrawers whole background.

Comment: What's your min-sdk version ? @Shaikh MD Ashiq

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `android:focusable="true"` in your custom row item for `RecyclerView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_row"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are u change background attribute ?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean ?

Comment: Recylcer View Need to add `android:focusable="true"` for focus do focus on particluar view and `android:clickable="true"` use for allow click on click on row. background effect is comming by `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"` on row parent view..

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Ripple effect by using [THIS LIBRARY](https://github.com/thomsonreuters/RippleDecoratorView).Include it in your Gradle files using.

```
compile 'com.thomsonreuters:rippledecoratorview:+'
```

Simply put your row layout in a **RippleDecoratorView**.For eg:

```
<com.thomsonreuters.rippledecoratorview.RippleDecoratorView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_margin="4dp"
  rdv:rdv_rippleColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
  rdv:rdv_rippleAnimationFrames="60"
  rdv:rdv_rippleAnimationPeakFrame="15"
  rdv:rdv_rippleMaxAlpha="0.8"
  rdv:rdv_rippleAnimationDuration="600"
  rdv:rdv_rippleRadius="50dp">



  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_row"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#F1F1F1" />


</RelativeLayout>

</com.thomsonreuters.rippledecoratorview.RippleDecoratorView>
```

Or you can use any of these libs acc to your requirement:

1>https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

2>https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView

3>https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Comment: I just want the user to get some feedback, when they are touching on a recycler row. This does not work.

Comment: Something like a ripple effect, which clicking on an row of the recyclerview.

Comment: I have having problem, putting this inside my row layout. Can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: @ShaikMDAshiq here see if it helps.

Comment: @ShaikMDAshiq have you added a click listener to your views and see if click is actually received?

Answer (score 1):

I can help you but I will need some feedback from you as well. In the `onCreateVIewHolder` inside your `recycler View adapter` you must have defined textViews and assigned it to the elements inside the sample recycler view. Add this. Make sure you define the layout outside the function so its accessible throughout the class

```
RelativeLayout layout;

layout=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById.(R.layout.drawer_row)
```

Then go to you recycler view adapter and in the `onBindViewHolder` define

```
holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override

 public void onClick(View v) {

 // Handle onClick event

     }
  });
```

In the onClick event you can add any kind of feedback you want to the user to experience such as starting a new activity, toasts, messages or in this case a ripple effect. You can use a custom library for ripples such as these

[Ripple effect for lollipop views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070269/ripple-effect-for-lollipop-views)

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/980

https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

Comment: Thanks. You were close. Actually, we should be using onTouch listener.

Comment: Thats true. Either way the format of implementing it is the same. If you want to add touch events to the individual images or texts within each recyclerview row then define their onClick / onTouch listener in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Ripple effects are not supported in pre-Lollipop devices.

Still use this [material-ripple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple)

```
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

Apply ripple on holder.drawView

```
MaterialRippleLayout.on(holder.drawerView)
           .rippleColor(Color.RED)
           .create();
```

Or you can apply from xml

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:id="@+id/ripple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button inside a ripple"/>

</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

Comment: I did this  holder.drawerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MaterialRippleLayout.on(holder.drawerView)
                        .rippleColor(Color.RED)
                        .create();
            }
        });

Comment: and then, it is sizing the view to wrapcontent.

Comment: Look at the demo project in library. He had applied Ripple effect on Recycler row item. And not like you. See [this](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/balysv/materialripple/demo/DemoRecyclerActivity.java)