# 9Patch on Lollipop shows gray oval in background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, nine-patch

I have the following button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/aecs_item_inner_padding_positive"
    android:id="@+id/aecsTelephone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/aecsServicesContainer"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Mobile"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_mobile_button" />
```

and it has the following background selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mobile_btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mobile_btn"></item>
</selector>
```

on Lollipop only the background shows an oval gray layer and I don't have any clue from where this layer is shown?

Note that using the none 9-patch version of the image fixes the problem, but I don't know why!

mobile_btn.9.png

[image]

Lollipop Screenshot:
[image]

KitKat Screenshot:
[image]

**Edit:**
The problem is solved. Okay..It was in the transparency of the 9-patch image, I used it from the hdpi folder and when it gets scaled the transparency area gets corrupted. However I am still shocked why on earth the problem shows up on Lollipop only. After I used the image as it is without any scale the problem is fixed.

Comment: Do you mean on `Lollipop` device or targetSDK?

Comment: The device, the first one is on Nexus 4 with Lollipop and other one is on S5 with KitKat, the target sdk is always 21.

Comment: For device, so you can refer to this post [Lollipop RippleDrawable vs Selector for Pre-Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607339/lollipop-rippledrawable-vs-selector-for-pre-lollipop)

Comment: @Xingchen I tried to encapsulate my 9patch inside the ripple xml but that didn't work as well. Please note that if I disable the 9patch and use normal image the problem is gone without using the ripple.

Comment: How about setting android:paddingMode=1 for the LayerDrawable?

Comment: Okay..The problem was in the transparency of the 9-patch image, I used it from the hdpi folder and when it gets scaled the transparency area gets corrupted. However I am still shocked why on earth the problem shows up on Lollipop only. After I used the image as it is without any scale the problem is fixed.

Comment: @MahdiHijazi what do you mean by `The problem was in the transparency of the 9-patch image`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextView` and set `android:focusable="true"` if you don't need the default `Button` styling. The `Button` widget is just a tiny set of properties on top of `TextView` and includes default elevation and z-depth animation.